# Two way one-to-many association in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

With NHibernate, how do I make both `user.AddPost(post)` and `post.setAuthor(user)` behave the same way?

Here are my classes:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Post> _posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get { return _posts; }
        set { _posts = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("User{{id={0}, name='{1}', age={2}}}", Id, Name, Age);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Post{{id={0}, text='{1}', author={2}}}", Id, Text, Author);
    }
}
```

Here are my mappings:

```
<class name="User" table="users">
  <id name="Id" type="int">
    <column name="Id" not-null="true" />
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" column="Name" />
  <property name="Age" column="Age" />
  <set name="Posts" inverse="true">
    <key column="AuthorId" />
    <one-to-many class="Post" />
  </set>
</class>

<class name="Post" table="posts">
  <id name="Id" type="int">
    <column name="Id" not-null="true" />
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Text" column="Text" />
  <many-to-one name="Author" column="AuthorId" class="User" />
</class>
```

The running code (works fine):

```
var user = new User {
  Name = "loki2302",
  Age = 100
};
session.Save(user);

var post = new Post {
  Text = "qwerty",
  Author = user
};
session.Save(post);
```

Is it possible to **also** enable this approach (doesn't work):

```
var user = new User {
  Name = "loki2302",
  Age = 100
};
session.Save(user);

var post = new Post {
  Text = "qwerty"
};
user.Posts.Add(post);
session.save(user);
```

?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Post in same process as you create a User? If it was Entity, I would create a Post inside the User. New User { .. new Post { } .. }

Comment: @Jonas: Well, I've just started learning NHibernate and I'm a little bit confused that though both approaches are fine whien compiling and running, there are just different result. To be more specific, I either need to make both approaches work fine, or for the second one (which isn't working) I'd like to get at least runtime errors, so I see it doesn't do what I expect it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it fails because of a NOT NULL constraint on the author column? You don't set the `Author` property in the `Post`, so NHibernate inserts NULL in the foreign key column.

If you need a two-way relationship create a `User.AddPost(Post)` method where you add the post to the collection and set the `Author` property of it.

If you only need a collection in your code (but not the `Author` reference), just remove the `Author` property (and its mapping), remove the `inverse="true"` of you collection mapping and add `not-null="true"` to the `key` element of your collection mapping. That way the collection will handle the reference from `Post` to `User`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you need to setup a cascading options for User entity.